# What would be the implications of proving Jesus Christ was an alien?

Tags: society, religion

Let's say that thanks to modern technology it could be proven that Jesus Christ was, in fact, an alien who came from another planet.

I won't go into the details of how it is done, but let's accept that proves leaves no doubt that Jesus came from a distant galaxy (at least thousands of light-years away).

Which might be the implications it would have in society?
I'm interested mainly in two aspects, though open to hearing others in case I hadn't taken them into account.

- How would believers react when knowing Jesus was an alien?
- How would scientists react when knowing there is alien life?

Comment: "How would scientists react when knowing there is alien life?"  is both way too broad, and opinion based. There was whole books and movies based on the idea "we know there is an intelligent alien life, but we don't know much about it".

Comment: Given that Jesus the Christ is God in His hypostasis of God the Son, he _is_ an alien, by definition. If you mean that the mortal man Isa bin Yusef al Nazri was an extra-terrestrial that would be only _slightly_ more interesting than proving that there actually was a real flesh-and-blood historical Isa bin Yusef al Nazri...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To your first question, "How would believers react when knowing Jesus was an alien?", they'll just believe your "evidence" is just a fabrication.
- To your second question, that would most likely increase the budget on spatial exploration, given we'd already have proof extraterrestrial life existed.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that he was born from a virgin is already an act of faith, so if it's proven that he came from the space is not that difficult to understand.

And if none of his words or acts changed, believers would still recognise him as the son of God.

And i guess scientists would try to find the way and the device he used to reach Earth, but that's just my opinion.